# Controlling the amplitude of the snake function in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I have been using TikZ with some success, but I can't figure out why the following code doesn't produce anything:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[decorate, decoration=snake, segment length=5mm, amplitude=15mm] (0,0) -- (10,10);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

except the following error

> Latex Error: ./untitled.tex:7 Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know
>   the key
>   '/tikz/amplitude' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled
>   it.

Were I to remove the amplitude option, this would compile. I just tried installing the very latest pgf-TikZ package, but that didn't change anything (the update went well, other features are working correctly). This leads me to believe that this option is somehow outdated, but I can't find anything to remedy this.

Does anyone know how to control the 'snake' amplitude in the latest TikZ package?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are missing a pair of braces. The line should be written as

```
\draw[decorate, decoration={snake, segment length=5mm, amplitude=15mm}] (0,0) -- (10,10);
```

`amplitude` is an option to `decoration` and not to `\path`, therefore the braces.

Comment: What do you know. It works! :) Do I feel silly. Those brackets don't seem to be needed until I add that third argument. Strange?

Comment: It is indeed strange that `segment length` can be given outside the grouping (`amplitude` can't even if it is the only argument). Maybe a bug for `segment length`.